# GD::Graph::histogram isn't working properly

Tags: perl, graph

I'm trying to use the [GD::Graph::histogram](http://search.cpan.org/~whizdog/GDGraph-histogram-1.1/lib/GD/Graph/histogram.pm), to create a histogram out of some data stored in a hash. My code looks like this:

```
sub __gen_pval_histogram {
    my ($tbl_ref, $outfile, $outdir) = @_;
    my $data = [values %$tbl_ref];
    foreach (@$data) {
        $_ = int( -1 * log($_)/log(10) );
    }

    my $hist = new GD::Graph::histogram(400,600);
    $hist->set (x_label      => "p-value",
        y_label      => "count",
        title        => "$outfile",
        x_labels_vertical => 1,
        bar_spacing  => 0,
        shadow_depth => 1,
        shadowclr    => 'dred',
        transparent  => 0,
    ) or warn $hist->error;

    my $out = $hist->plot($data) or die $hist->error;

    open my $file, ">", "$outdir/$outfile" or
        die "Couldn't open $outdir/$outfile: '$?'";
    binmode $file;
    print {$file} $out->png;
    print "Created histogram at $outdir/$outfile\n";
}

my %hash = (a => 0.0000009, b => 0.000034, c => 0.00045, d => 0.0000000012, e => 0.00000098);

__gen_pval_histogram \%hash, "hist.png", ".";
```

Running this generates an error when calling the plot function and generates a wrong histogram:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.4/GD/Graph/histogram.pm line 42.
```

Obviously something is wrong with the way I pass the data to the function. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Edited some data into the OP.

Comment: Try running it with [Carp::Always](http://p3rl.org/Carp::Always) to see how exactly do you hit this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 42 in GD::Graph::Histogram refers to parameter histogram_type, which should be defaulted to Count, but looks like default does not work.

So try to include

```
histogram_type => 'count',
```